# When do we need to take into account repeated letters for permutations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

When asked to arrange the number of ways ‘MISSISSIPPI’ be arranged, we take into account repeated letters (11! / 4!2!4!).

However when asked how many possible 3 character length variable names can be made out of the letters (A-Z), why can we just use 26^3 and ignore repeated letters?

Answer (score 1):

The second question is fundamentally different from the first. It doesn't ask how many ways you can *arrange* the letters A-Z, it asks how many 3-character strings you can make *using* those letters. The equivalent for MISSISSIPPI would be "how many 3-character strings can you make using the letters in MISSISSIPPI?", to which the answer would be $4^3$, since there are 4 distinct letters in MISSISSIPPI (M, I, S, P).

If you were to ask how many 3-character strings you could make using the letters A-Z (without replacement), the answer would be $26P3 = 26\cdot 25\cdot 24$, not $26^3$. Furthermore, I should mention that the letters A-Z have no repeating characters like MISSISSIPPI does.

Comment: Actually, $4^3$ is the number of $3$-character strings you can make using the letters M, I, S, P.  It is not the number of $3$-character strings you can make using the letters of MISSISSIPPI since M can only appear once and P can only appear twice.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified: $4^3$ is the number of 3-character strings you can make using the letters in MISSISSIPPI _with replacement_.